# Bulletproof - Is it possible to do range proof only from public key?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm

is it possible to proof x in range (2^1,2^64) from xG=Q with bulletproof or something else only from Q? I’m new in this subject, so thanks before.

Comment: Note that the range for bulletproofs range proofs is of the form $[0; 2^b]$, not $[2;2^b]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to generate a proof only with the knowledge of $Q$; you need the knowledge of $x$.

If it were possible to generate a proof (or fail to generate a proof if $x$ were out of the range), then it would be possible to efficiently recover the value of $x$ by attempting to generate a range proof for $Q - yG = (x - y)G$ for various values of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The Bulletproofs scheme is a system to generate zero-knowledge *proofs of knowledge*. The range proof system is a very specific *proof of knowledge*. It proves the statement "I **know** $x$ such that $x \in [0;2^b]$ and $xG=Q$" for some $b$ and $Q$.

Since in your situation you don't know $x$, you cannot prove such a statement.